# Remote server scheduled task

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, remote-server

I am looking to program a simple "data push" service, that extracts data out of a SQL Server database, and deposits a CSV file to a remote FTP site every ten minutes.  This service will be running on a remote server, managed over TeamViewer.

There are a few ways I've thought to do this, but would like a bit of advice as to which is the best and most reliable method.  A few pro's and cons would also be very helpful from people who have experience in this type of work.

Possible solutions:

- Windows service with use of Thread.Sleep(..) to run task every ten minutes
- Simple EXE console project that runs as a Windows Scheduler task
- Windows service with use of a Timer class
- Any other methods?

The program will be written in C#, but I am very flexible in terms of project type, design etc.

The main requirement of this service is to be reliable, and I'd also look to build in an alerts system to notify on failure.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would favour a scheduled task for this kind of application, as it's far easier to make changes to the schedule at a later date.

There's a previous question along a similar line here: [Windows Service or Task Scheduler for maintenance tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481760/windows-service-or-task-scheduler-for-maintenance-tasks)